# Custom links to switch language in Drupal 6

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

In my case, I wanted to print the language switch links directly in page.tpl.php, for example with:

```
<a href="what_to_put_here">English</a>
<a href="what_to_put_here">Deutsch</a>
```

How can I accomplish this without using the "Language switcher" block? I checked all the modules that comes with the Internationalization project, but I didn't see any `hook_block()` implementation that outputs the language switcher block.

UPDATED:
I wanted something like: This site is on **russian**, **english** and **kazakh** languages.
This cannot be done with language switcher block.

i've tried this way in page.tpl.php:

```
<?php
$way = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' : $_GET['q'];
print '<span id="switcher">'. 'на ' . l('русском', $way). ', ' . l('казахском', 'kk/'.$way). ' и ' . l('английском', 'en/'.$way) .'</span>';
?>
```

Default language is russian - mysite.com, when i switch to an english - mysite.com/en, as you see it adds prefix 'en'. But now if i want to switch on kazakh language - mysite.com/kk from english the link looks mysite.com/en/kk == it adds en to my URL. How to make this correctly?

Comment: I'm curious, does the language switcher has the same behavior ?

Comment: Have you tried to put the alter in your code `drupal_alter('translation_link', $links, $path);` and deal with the `$links` array ?

Comment: problem is theme('links', $links, array()); outputs all links together. And i need to put some text before russian, english and kazakh translation links.

Comment: Yes sure but you're not obliged to use `theme('links'` just use `$links` the way you want with your own code `foreach ($links as $key => $link) {`. Check out the [theme_links](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_links/6) documentation. Does the `$links` array output something useful for you ?

Comment: Thanks, can you throw me an example, while im trying to do it myself :)

Comment: Im not succeeded :( Can you help with an example please.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

What doesn't work for you with the language switcher ?
If you want to reproduce its behavior, have a look at its [code](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal--modules--locale--locale.module/function/locale_block/6) and try to do something equal.

Here is some code:

```
$path = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' : $_GET['q'];
$languages = language_list('enabled');
$links = array();
foreach ($languages[1] as $language) {
  $links[$language->language] = array(
    'href' => $path, 
    'title' => $language->native, 
    'language' => $language, 
    'attributes' => array('class' => 'language-link'),
  );
}
drupal_alter('translation_link', $links, $path);
//dpm($links);

foreach ($links as $link) {
  echo t('Link for ') . l($link['title'], $link['href']) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: check my updated question please.

Comment: Thanks, but how it would determine which $link for russian and which for english? for example i want to put some russian text before russian translation link, and some english text before english translation link.

Comment: tested your code - it doesn't works correctly - when im on russian language and trying to switch to english -> english link href attribut looks like admin/build/block without en prefix.

Comment: `admin/build/block` is an admin path and I think these don't have special paths. Have you tried on a normal node which have two translations ? Because this code is exactly the language switcher code, I just added an echo at the beginning.

Comment: I've already tried this code on a normal node with 3 translations - no effect...

Comment: And each translation has its path ? Because as said earlier, this code is strait from the language switcher block, so I'm out of ideas :/

Comment: each translation has it path. Russian - ru, English - en, Kazakh - kk. :((

Answer (score 1):

Use the `language` option of the [l() function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/6). Same URL, different language and Drupal should take care of it for you:

```
<?php
$way = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' : $_GET['q'];
$languages = language_list();
print l('slovak', $way, array('language' => $languages['sk'])) . ', '
  . l('czech', $way, array('language' => $languages['cs'])) . ', '
  . l('english', $way, array('language' => $languages['en']));
?>
```

Comment: it doesn't works, mate. Links is now without any prefixes, just for example - admin/build/block (even if im on kazakh version it doesn't adds en prefix)

Comment: Sorry, the language option is supposed to be a language object, not just its code. Tested this time. ;-)

Comment: it doesn't works :( Same behaviour as before. If i belong at admin/build/block - the link on kazakh and other versions is still admin/build/block without any prefixes...

Comment: Hm... Make sure to configure the "Language negotiation" to "Path prefix *" at the Languages | Configure page.

Comment: it's already set to path prefix

Comment: That's weird... Can you share a link to that website? Have you got the languages installed via Languages | Add language page? BTW, does the Language switcher block do for you at all? I just got that and my custom block running on the same page...